# How to extract the ID of a Category from Product using Product ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller

I am trying to write a LINQ query to get me the id of a category to be used in a Redirect request. The only information I will have is a product ID. All products belong to 1 Category.

When I click a category from "Category/Index/ I am taken to "Product/Index/[Category ID]" with all the products specific to that category ID. When I delete one of the products, the delete action of the products controller should redirect me to the same page "Product/Index/[Category ID]". At the moment I am directed to "Product/Index" which is invalid request. I need to go to an index page with a category ID in the request.

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have:

`var catID = db.Categories.SelectMany(p => p.Products.Select(x => x.Id == id));`

Comment: What is Redirect request redirecting to? Have you tried to write any LINQ yourself? What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Which ids do you want? What would be your desired output?

Comment: take a look at my updated answer

Comment: I think you need to save the category ID on the Product table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `id` contains your product id:

`var catId = db.Categories.Single(category => category.Products.Any(product => product.Id == id)).Id`

This will throw an exception if the given `id` doesn't exist in any category. If you don't want that, you can use:

```
var category = db.Categories.SingleOrDefault(category => category.Products.Any(product => product.Id == id));
if (category == null)
{
    // handle error
}
else
{
    var catId = category.Id;
    // do your work with catId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the product exists and that it belongs to any category, the following should work:

```
db.Categories.Single(c => c.Products.Any(p => p.Id == id)).Id
```

Comment: I don't see a `Category` property inside the `Product` object

Comment: Sorry, question was edided. Gonna edit my answer accordingly.